# Should I alphabetically order the flags in a command as good practice?

Tags: command-line

I know that these two commands do the same thing:

```
ls -la
ls -al
```

but I'm wondering if there is any preference between them. Is it better practice to order them in a certain way?

Comment: You also need this t-shirt: http://www.redbubble.com/people/digerati/works/5017109-i-have-cdo-it-s-like-ocd-but-all-the-letters-are-in-alphabetical-order-as-they-should-be?p=t-shirt  :)

Comment: @Sergey Awesome shirt!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does not really matter* unless a command explicitly mentions. I have came across no reference that gave anything like a guideline how to put the options one after another. So I think for the sake of readability the options can be arranged alphabetically.

*There is a very very important cavaet that is if any option needs a filename or any other input right after it you need to put it accordingly.

For example, the `-f` option of `grep` takes a file as input to take the pattern to look for from the input file. You need to give the command as e.g.:

```
grep -cf input.txt file.txt
```

If you use it like:

```
grep -fc input.txt file.txt
```

it will fail as it will use `c` as a file name.

Answer (score 12):

The *POSIX* conventions define in [Guideline 11 and 12 of the Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) that the order "**should not matter**" unless it's not documented for the utility itself.

The *GNU C Library Reference Manual* also honors those POSIX conventions in [25.1.1 Program Argument Syntax Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).

But notice, there are several utilities that give in some situations strict orders how to perform the parameters (for example find). From the [find manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/find.1.html):

> The `-name` test comes before the `-type` test in  order  to  avoid
>          having to call `stat(2)` on every file.

Sometimes the utility complains about the ordering.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `find` only has a few options, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_04) only defines the two options `-H` and `-L`. The GNU `find` in Ubuntu has a few more options, but `-type` and `-name` etc are considered *operators*, not *options*. And for operators, order usually matters.

Answer (score 5):

With ls you can hardly go wrong with ordering of options.

But be mindful though that other commands can have different responses to options depending on the order.

An example is the find command. You will get different results for example between:

```
  find . -ls -mtime -1
```

And

```
  find . -mtime -1 -ls
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to practice is alphabetizing short strings, perhaps. I find two strategies useful: making words (reduces typos) and making sentences (improves understanding).

For ls, for instance, I usually use `ls -halF` because, even with the strange capitalization, I am better at typing *halF* than something like *Falh* that isn't a word.

For tar, on the other hand, I type `tar czvf filename` and say (in my head) "tar Create and Zip, Verbosely For filename" because that's how I learned what the different letters meant.

Comment: I remember e2fsck -fvcckt because it spells the situation I may be in if it returns too many errors. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have answered, it doesn't matter (unless documented otherwise or option arguments take further arguments).

But is it preferable to order options alphabetically is debatable.

Personally, I find that mnemonics provide more value than strict alphabetic order.  It is easier to remember a set of options when they form a memorable word, for example, consider:

```
netstat -tan
# alphabetic is good (by chance) in this case
netstat -ant
```

vs:

```
netstat -atn
netstat -nta
```

So if you find yourself repeating a certain combo of options for a command, you may want to try and rearrange the letters to an order that is easiest for you to remember.